# iOS MapKit throws error: "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: \314CGRectIsEmpty"

Tags: ios, mapkit

I started developing my own navigation map in objective C, but recently got to dead end situation with MapKit.

I have XCode 4.5, iOS target set to 6.0. and MapKit framework loaded through Link Binary With Libraries.

Error look like this:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: \314CGRectIsEmpty
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics

dyld: Symbol not found: \314CGRectIsEmpty
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
```

When I started, It worked just fine, but then I added features like toolbar items and currentLocation button, and this wild error started to appear. First I thought there is something wrong with my code. But then I had program that worked, and added feature, it started throwing this error, and when I put it back, error still lasts. Here is the code from MapViewController.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // 1
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 50.07499;
    zoomLocation.longitude= 14.43976;
    // 2
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 10000, 10000);
    // 3
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    // 4
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
    if (self.mapView.userLocationVisible){
        self.currentLocationButton.enabled = YES;
    }else{
        self.currentLocationButton.enabled = NO;
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.00 target:self selector:@selector(checkGeolocationAvailible) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [timer fire];
    }






}

- (IBAction)checkGeolocationAvailible {
    if (self.mapView.userLocationVisible){
        self.currentLocationButton.enabled = YES;
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}

- (IBAction)showCurrentLocation {
    if (self.mapView.userLocationVisible){
        [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: do you have `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` in your source?

Comment: Hi, I did not. I added it + some other libraries just in case, but still no change. I found out that when I comment the code starting with the line 

MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];

and everything under it started to work. But when I uncomment this line, it crashes again. Even though that worked maybe 5 hours ago.